# Subscription discount history

Tags: python, braintree

I am working on a billing history page to show customers, based on a braintree subscription. While the braintree api generally has all the information I need, I'm having trouble with *discounts*.

In the braintree control panel, a subscription will show a 'history' section below the transaction section, which tracks changes in the price/balance of a subscription. The data in this section can be found in the [Subscription result object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/python), under `status_history` (for reference, I'm using the python api).

The one piece of data I cannot seem to find is a discount history. In the history section, the Add-ons/Discounts column will show the number of discounts and the total discount amount on a specific history event.

In the Subscription result object, the `status_history` list has no discount information, and the `discounts` list seems to only contain discounts which have not yet been applied (making it useless for historical purposes).

So, I guess my question is: **Is there a way, through the braintree python api, to retrieve a list of discounts, containing historical information like date created/applied and discount amount?**

EDIT: I checked the braintree node library as well. I grabbed the same subscription I was using with the python library. The subscription result object also has an empty `discounts` list when there are no recent discounts.

EDIT 2:
Here is my method of accessing the subscription:

in the braintree control panel, on the page for the specific subscription, there is a subscription id entry:

[image]

on the same page, at the bottom of the the "History" section, I can see that there has been, at some point, a discount for the subscription:

[image]

so I grab the subscription in python:

```
In [1]: import braintree
In [2]: sub = braintree.Subscription.find('fkr6sr')
In [3]: sub.id
Out[3]: u'fkr6sr'
In [4]: sub.discounts
Out[4]: []
```

I would expect `sub.discounts` to have exactly one entry.

FINAL EDIT: For future reference, the empty `sub.discounts` is expected behavior. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311842/subscription-discount-history/38333397?noredirect=1#comment64132174_38333397). I've marked the parent post as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The Subscription result object has attributes [add_ons](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/python#add_ons) and [discounts](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/python#discounts) which are arrays of those respective objects. You can infer the date the modification was applied depending on the `Discount.current_billing_cycle` attribute in combination with the `Subscription.next_billing_date` attribute, as well as the total modification amount by drawing from `Discount.amount` and `Discount.quantity`.

An example implementation may look like:

```
subscription_result_object = (Subscription.search(...)).first
discount = subscription_result_object.discounts[0]
billing_period = subscription_result_object.billing_period_end_date - subscription_result_object.billing_period_start_date
discount_start_date = subscription_result_object.next_billing_date - (discount.current_billing_cycle * billing_period)
total_discount = discount.amount * discount.quantity
```

Comment: How about old discounts? I see a discount in the control panel from may 2015 on a subscription, but `subscription_result_object.discounts` is `[]`

Comment: As long as the discount is still associated with the subscription it should show up; expired discounts are not automatically removed. If you are sure that you have found the correct subscription (Subscription.search() returns a collection of them that you must iterate over), try matching on the `id` returned from a [Discount.all()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/discount/all/python) call.

Comment: would finding the subscription through `braintree.Subscription.search(...)` give different results than `braintree.Subscription.find(<subscription_id_copied_from_control_panel>)`? I've tried it both ways, and the `discounts` list is still empty.

Comment: I've edited the question to (hopefully) be a little more clear.

Comment: I was wrong, expired discounts do in fact become disassociated with their subscriptions. It will therefore not be possible to retrieve a complete history from API calls; one solution would be to store some historical data on your own when subscriptions are created or updated.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's what I was afraid of, as all the subscriptions I'm working with are at least a year old. Thank you for your response!